# How to determine the correct number of running threads in Linux?

Tags: linux

I work on a Linux virtual machine, and I often experience issues when running a program:

> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create failed for thread 28 of 32:
> Resource temporarily unavailable OpenBLAS blas_thread_init:
> RLIMIT_NPROC 1031747 current, 1031747 max

The fact is

> ulimit -u

does return 1031747.

But when I run the following command to get the number of running threads :

> ps -eo nlwp | tail -n +2 | awk '{ num_threads += $1 } END { print
> num_threads }'

I get 12982... How can the 1031747 limit be reached?